# Relay Command doesn't execute

Tags: data-binding, winui-3, windows-community-toolkit

I've decided to use the mvvm architecture in my project and tried converting my code to it.
But it looks like I'm misunderstanding something, as the properties I'd like to set in an relay command are either not changed or the changing has no effect. Either way this behavior is not desired.

My code is very simple and looks like this:

MainViewModel.cs

```cs
public partial class MainViewModel : ObservableRecipient
{
    [ObservableProperty] private string testText;

    [RelayCommand]
    private void Toggle()
    {
        testText = "pressed";
    }
}
```

Mainview.xaml

```xml
<Page
    x:Class="Calendarium.Views.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    xmlns:viewModels="using:Calendarium.ViewModels"
    d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=viewModels:MainViewModel}">
    <Grid>
         <TextBlock Text="{Binding TestText}">
         <Button Command="{Binding ToggleCommand}">
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have set the *design time* `DataContext` only.

You also need to set the actual `DataContext` that is used at runtime:

```
<Page
    x:Class="Calendarium.Views.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    xmlns:viewModels="using:Calendarium.ViewModels"
    d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=viewModels:MainViewModel}">
    <Page.DataContext>
        <viewModels:MainViewModel />
    </Page.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        ...
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Besides, you should set the value of the generated *property* in your `Toggle` method:

```
[RelayCommand]
private void Toggle()
{
    TestText = "pressed";
}
```

Comment: Looks like I've followed an outdated tutorial. He were using the `x:Datatype` to bind it. However it works now! Thanks for your help.